# Como colocar itens em uma Listview

Tags: android, xamarin

O método `add` não aparece, sou novo então nem faço ideia do que pode ser

```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        ListView lista = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
        lista.Add();

    }
```

Comment: Matheus conseguiu resolver seu problema com a resposta? Ou precisa de mais alguma informação?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.widget.ListView/setAdapter

Aqui tem os exemplos.

Você precisa do "listview" e adicionar um Adapter, com o setAdapter();

Veja os exemplo, é coisa simples.

Answer (score 1):

A classe [**`ListView`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) não possui método `Add`. Você primeiro precisa criar um `List` ou `ArrayList` para para que você possa listar dentro do seu `ListView`.